# Topological mapping of open disk onto whole plane

Tags: general-topology

> Construct a topological mapping of the open disk $|z|<1$ onto the whole plane.

I represent $z=re^{i\theta}$. I thought about the bijection from $(0,1)$ to $(0,\infty)$, which is given by $x\rightarrow \dfrac1x-1$. Applying this to the norm, we will get the mapping $re^{i\theta}\rightarrow\left(\dfrac1r-1\right)e^{i\theta}$. The only problem is that the point $0$ has not been mapped to or from yet. If I map $0$ to itself, the map becomes non-continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t flip it: just expand it. To do this, you must multiply $z$ by a factor that increases without bound as $|z|\to 1$; one natural choice is $(1-|z|)^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try another bijection between $(0,1)$ and $(0,+\infty)$.

> $\tan \frac{\pi x}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Put a sphere on a plane. Draw a line from the center $M$ of the sphere to a point $P$ in the plane. This line intersects the surface of lower hemisphere of the sphere in a point $Q$. so you get a 1-1 mapping from the surface of the lower hemisphere to the plan. Draw  Line through $Q$ vertical to the plane. This line intersects the plane in $R$. This gives you a 1-1 mapping from the lower hemisphere to the projection of this hemispere to the plane which is disk. Both give you a 1-1 from the open disk to the plane. A beam through $R$ vertical to the plane is mirrored by the sphere in $Q$ to $P$.
[image]