# Brouwer's fixed point continuous function

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, game-theory, fixed-point-theorems

Can anyone point me out the continuous functions without brouwer fixed point's for the following sets

$$A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x_1,x_2 \geq 0 \text{ and }x_1^2+x_2^2 = 1 \}$$
$$B = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x_1,x_2 \geq 0 \text{ and }2 \geq x_1^2+x_2^2 \geq 1 \}$$
$$C = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x_1^2+x_2^2 < 1 \}$$

How should one be designing continuous functions without fixed point? Is there any specific method is it just a guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A$ is homeomorphic to the line segment $[-1,1]$, which always has fixed points.

$B$: rotate.

$C$ is homeomorphic to the plane. In the plane, a translation will do.

Comment: Can you give any examples for homeomorphic transformations? i am not very familiar with that concept i am studying about it now.

Comment: For $A$, just map $(x_1,x_2)$ to $x_1$. Call the map $h:A\to [-1,1]$. You should be able to prove that if $f:A\to A$ has a fixed point, then $h\circ f\circ h^{-1}:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]$ has a fixed point, and vice versa.

Comment: For $C$, you can see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478517/topological-mapping-of-open-disk-onto-whole-plane .